# How to properly call one method from another method

Tags: python, class, methods

How to properly call one method from another in python.
I get some data from the AWS S3 bucket after I want to sort this data and write it into a .txt.

```
import boto3
import string
import json
import collections


def handler(event, context):
    print(f'Event: {event}')

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket(event["bucket"])

    for obj in bucket.objects.all():
        key = obj.key
        body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
        b = json.loads(body)
        c = WordCorrection.create_duplicated_words_file(b)
        # WordCorrection.create_duplicated_words_file(WordCorrection.word_frequency(
        #     WordCorrection.correct_words(b)))
        # WordCorrection.spell_words(WordCorrection.dict_spell_words(WordCorrection.unrecognized_words_from_textrtact(b)))

        return c
      


CONFIDENT_LEVEL = 98


class WordCorrection:
    def correct_words(data):
        spell = SpellChecker()
        correct_words_from_amazon = []
        for items in data['Blocks']:
            if items['BlockType'] == "WORD" and items['Confidence'] > CONFIDENT_LEVEL and {items["Text"]} != spell.known([items['Text']]):
                correct_words_from_amazon.append(items['Text'])
        correct_words_from_amazon = [''.join(c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation) for s in
                                     correct_words_from_amazon]

        return correct_words_from_amazon

    def word_frequency(self, correct_words_from_amazon):
        word_counts = collections.Counter(correct_words_from_amazon)
        word_frequency = {}
        for word, count in sorted(word_counts.items()):
            word_frequency.update({word: count})

        return dict(sorted(word_frequency.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))

    def create_duplicated_words_file(word_frequency):
        with open("word_frequency.txt", "w") as filehandle:
            filehandle.write(str(' '.join(word_frequency)))
```

I was trying to use `self` but I cannot see a good result, and from the reason I use

```
WordCorrection.create_duplicated_words_file(WordCorrection.word_frequency(WordCorrection.correct_words(b)))
```

but I'm in 100% sure that it is not correct, there is another way to call one method from another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your trouble is the result of a misunderstanding about keywords/namespaces for modules vs classes.

### Modules:

In python, [files are modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) so when you are inside of a file, all functions defined up to that point in the file are "in scope." So if I have two functions like this:

```py
def func_foo():
    return "foo"
def func_bar():
    return func_foo() + "bar"
```

Then `func_bar()` will return `"foobar"`.

### Classes

When you define a class using the `class` keyword, that defines a new scope/namespace. It is considered proper (although technically not required) to use the word `self` as the first parameter to an instance method, and this refers to the instance the method is called upon.

For example:

```py
class my_clazz:
    def method_foo(self):
        return "foo" 
    def method_bar(self):
        return self.method_foo() + "bar"
```

Then if I have later in the file:

```
example = my_clazz()
ret_val = example.method_bar()
```

`ret_val` will be `"foobar"`

That said, because I did not really utilize object-oriented programming features in this example, the class definition was largely unnecessary.

### Your Issue

So for your issue, it seems like your trouble is caused by what appears to be unnecessarily wrapping your functions inside a class definition. If you got rid of the class definition header and just made all of your functions in the module you would be able to use the calling techniques I used above. For more information on classes in Python I'd recommend reading [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).